# C# import/export data to Mailclient

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am currently working on a program to export/import data from other mail clients to outlook.
So far it seems I have two options available.

1. I learn how to write to a pst file so I can easily import the necessary data.
2. I create a different, self-made connection.

I am not asking which one I should use but rather on some advice because so far while planning I ran across a few things with each method that might turn out to be too much of problem.

1. So far I couldn't find an existing library that allows writing to a .pst file. I am lucky to finally have found a library that allows reading the pst file that is open source.
2. I haven't found a way yet to programmatically create a new mail item in the inbox. I have been able to create a new email that can be sent but no email yet that is "incoming".

Comment: pst is a proprietary closed format, you will not likely manage to use it for writing, and it is a subject of a suit, if you do not mind, please read license agreemen for office product including Outlook, you have to decompile it to manage how it works, and license you agree when install Outlook declines and prohibits this, even if you get somehow .pst file, it still under license terms, so, it is not good idea to write something you do not own in sources

Comment: Why do you want to work with PST files? What if the user wants to import into an existing Exchange (or Office 365) account? Are you planning on sending these PST files to the user so that they can be opened standalone? Or are you doing that on a machine different from the one where the end user will open it?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into outlook interop? 
depending on how your application will function it is a great way to interact with outlook at a high level, you can easily create mailItems, calendar, memos etc.

Comment: But does it also allow to create a mailItem not as an outgoing email but as an incoming email?

Comment: Yea, at the moment I do this for scanned incoming mail, so when a pdf scan comes in I will attach it to a mail item and save it in the relevant folder with subject and who it is to. Weird use case but it works

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask again because I don't quite understand: What I need to do is my programm to get all existing emails from for example tobit david and then import them to outlook. So what I need to have exported is the email I got in tobit david and the import it as a mail with the original sender I got it from.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a temporary IMAP account on whatever IMAP server you like best (whether that be GMail, Yahoo!Mail, some other free IMAP account, or a local Exchange/Dovecot/etc server).

Then, once you've got that setup, export mail from Mail Client X to the IMAP server and then add the temporary IMAP account to Outlook and copy them all into your Outlook folders.

Comment: That is how it is similar to how I currently do it. My goal would be to automate that process.